# Remove case sensitivity from username when logging in

Tags: users

When I try to login, my usernames are treated as case sensitive. As in if username is `john` and I try entering `John`, it is not accepted.

Is it possible if I could make all the characters lower case before they could be submitted?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [hook_user_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7), you can convert every letter of username to lower case once a user is being created. Then when a user is submitting the login form, you can convert its username field to lower case. So from now on all of the usernames will be in lower case it is no longer case sensitive

Comment: Just a note, you also need to disable permission to edit usernames (`Change own username`) for that users group. Because if you not, this hook will not be sufficient and you will need to use [hook_user_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_update/7) also.